# GSON проблема с десериализацией

Tags: java, json, java-ee, gson

есть вот такой код

```
gson  = new GsonBuilder()
            .setDateFormat(DateFormat.FULL, DateFormat.FULL).create();
```

пробовал делать и вот так

```
gson  = new GsonBuilder()
            .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").create();
```

ставить

`setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX").create();
setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz").create(); 
setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ").create();`

тоже пробовал
при десериализации джсона в объект

`gson.fromJson(string, object.getClass());`

всегда одна и та же самая ошибка

`Exception in thread "Thread-3" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: 1469504907000
    at com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.deserializeToDate(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:106)
    at com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.deserialize(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:83)
    at com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.deserialize(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:37)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TreeTypeAdapter.read(TreeTypeAdapter.java:69)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:887)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:852)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:801)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:773)
    at jsmarty.core.common.json.JsonHandler.deserialize(JsonHandler.java:79)
    at jsmarty.core.router.SdoRouteWorkerThread.run(SdoRouteWorkerThread.java:71)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Failed to parse date ["1469504907000']: Invalid time zone indicator '0'
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.util.ISO8601Utils.parse(ISO8601Utils.java:274)
    at com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.deserializeToDate(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:104)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid time zone indicator '0'
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.util.ISO8601Utils.parse(ISO8601Utils.java:245)
    ... 13 more`

Comment: Попсмотрите ответы [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8960644/3212712) -  возможно, дело в том, что у вас дата в виде timeStamp, а не date

Comment: @ЮрийСПб 
дата приходит в timeStamp , в объекте тип даты date. разве Gson не должен это преобразовать?

Comment: Ну, видимо не умеет. Надо ему помочь. По ссылке выше я два примера видел разных - попробуйте их

Comment: @ЮрийСПб
я переходил по ссылке) и попытался решить свою проблему так как там описано но к сожелению проблема не ушла( ошибка таже самая

Answer (score 1):

```
public static class GsonUTCDateAdapter implements JsonSerializer<Date>,JsonDeserializer<Date> {

    private final DateFormat dateFormat;

    public GsonUTCDateAdapter() {
      dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.US);      //This is the format I need
      dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));                               //This is the key line which converts the date to UTC which cannot be accessed with the default serializer
    }

    @Override public synchronized JsonElement serialize(Date date,Type type,JsonSerializationContext jsonSerializationContext) {
        return new JsonPrimitive(dateFormat.format(date));
    }

    @Override public synchronized Date deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement,Type type,JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) {
      try {
        return dateFormat.parse(jsonElement.getAsString());
      } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw new JsonParseException(e);
      }
    }
}
```

Затем:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new GsonUTCDateAdapter()).create();
Date now=new Date();
System.out.println(gson.toJson(now));
```

Comment: [Здесь подробнее](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/281)